# How can i get all the values using vise versa column from database in mySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get data using vise versa column from database in mySql Database.

For example, see following image.
[image]

Above image you can see column name **initiator_user_id** & **friend_user_id** column , So I want all the those `friends_user_id and initiator_user_id`  that are in stored in both column. So here `1` is stored in both column so i want 89,63,155 ids that are stored in both column.

I have tried to get record using **CASE** Statement but it'll not work.

SQL Query..

```
 SELECT *,
CASE
    WHEN friend_user_id != '' THEN initiator_user_id 
    WHEN initiator_user_id != '' THEN friend_user_id 
    ELSE ''
END AS users_id
FROM tablename
```

Someone please let me know , How could i get those records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handful of ways this could be done - I quickly threw together a UNION DISTINCT statement on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcbc7f/1) that may help. Essentially it's just taking two queries and putting them together to get you your results.

```
(SELECT initiator_user_id as user_id FROM test WHERE friend_user_id = 1) 
UNION DISTINCT 
(SELECT friend_user_id as user_id FROM test WHERE initiator_user_id = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you want to get the users and all of his friends.

```
select initiator_user_id,GROUP_CONCAT(friend_user_id) as all_his_friends from (
select 
initiator_user_id,friend_user_id
from users
UNION 
select 
friend_user_id,initiator_user_id
from users ) t 
GROUP BY initiator_user_id
```

You can try playing with this SQLfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/642e1dc/3